# Turn on multi-threading in Oracle for ETL purposes

Tags: oracle, parallelism, informatica

As you can see from this question, I was able to configure multi-threading in SQL Server and build a workflow in Informatica to multi-thread a job to move data faster into SQL Server.

[Multi-thread Informatica connections to use different processors on target database server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107966/multi-thread-informatica-connections-to-use-different-processors-on-target-datab)

Now I'd like to do the same thing in Oracle.  Does anyone know the feature in Oracle that's comparable to the "Max Degree of Parallelism" setting in SQL Server?  I'd like to move data on each core of the server in parallel.

I'm strictly dealing with `INSERT` statements.  So DML.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to SQL Server, Oracle has way more parameters that control parallel execution (also, parallel execution may be not available depends on edition). Check [Using Parallel Execution](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/usingpe.htm) in the Database Data Warehousing Guide – https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2232

---

Query portion of a DML statement is the `SELECT` part of `INSERT INTO foo SELECT smth FROM bar`, as an example. By the way, parallel DML can only happen in case of multirow inserts. If you insert rows one by one, no parallelism can be attained.

However, from your other question it seems that you are basically asking whether workloads from multiple concurrent connections will be executed on the database server in parallel, in which case the answer is yes regardless of the `PARALLEL DML` setting (or `MAXDOP` on SQL Server, for that matter). – https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721